# Any reason why Rails credentials wouldn't work in Initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any reason why I couldn't use

```
 Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym]['amazon']['client_id']
```

in

```
config/initializers/omniauth.rb
```

Currently when I do, I get:

```
config/initializers/omniauth.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: What version of Rails 5 is this? [I believe credentials were added in 5.2](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2).

Comment: yeah its 5.2, at the same time as the below answer went up I figured i should be doing symbol not strings.
Time to have a break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of those `[]` calls could be the culprit.

It could be that `Rails.application.credentials` is nil.

It could be that `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym]` is nil.

It could be that `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym]['amazon']` is nil.

This should all be easy enough to test which one it is.

I'm going to guess it's because of using `amazon` as a string instead of a symbol. If your `config/credentials.yml.enc` looks like this...

```
production:
  amazon:
    client_id: 12345
```

Then try using symbol keys. Though it is possible this is a hash with indifferent access.

```
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:amazon][:client_id]
```